# Mobile Chatroom with Azure

Tags: azure, mobile, instant-messaging

I'm currently looking into developing a mobile app using Microsoft Azure as my backend. So far everything that I have needed is pretty much built right in.

Anyway, the app I am making is a messaging app that has multi-user chatrooms. I've never done any backend programming and now I have to learn everything at once.

I looked at Azure documentation and noticed the Azure Service Bus feature may be what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do implement such a service.

Obviously I want a way for users to synchronously and asynchronously receive messages. Synchronously while they are actively using the app on their phone and asynchronously while it is in the background (load new messages from the queue when the app becomes active again).

The service bus has **Topics** which I understand allows a publisher-subscriber type messaging architecture, however I believe clients still have to query the Topic queue (send a request) to receive data. This is not ideal because I don't want to just hard-code a loop that queries the cloud service bus every second or so to achieve a psuedo-realtime chat... This would probably inflate server costs as my userbase grows.

The service bus also has **Relays** which I understand to allow two-way communication between a service bus and a client as well as enables synchronous messaging that builds on the publisher-subscriber architecture of Topics (Relays are combined with Topics, right?).

Additionally, each chatroom can have its own Topic, and users that join said chatroom subscribe to the Topic.

What I think I could do is: I could have the app connect to the service bus via a relay while the user is actively using the app (it's in the forefront) and the user will receive realtime chat. When the user locks the phone or otherwise puts the app into the background, I can terminate the Relay connection and when the user reloads the app, I can download messages from the queue that were not received already.

I want to know if service buses are recommended for this kind of messaging or if I have the idea behind them all wrong. What would you recommend for this kind of service? I'm open to other ideas but I'd rather keep the server-side stuff rather light. I have a lot of frontend to learn already!

Thanks!

Don

Comment: This is really an opinion question, as there's no right answer. Between Service Bus, web sockets, polling, push notifications, etc. there are many choices. You should look into limitations around topics and subscribers to see if Service Bus will scale along with your app (and then there's Azure Event Hubs which scale further). So... lots of options, no single right answer...

Answer (score 0):

have a look at SignalR as well.

there's even a sample chat app using Azure Mobile Services with SignalR - have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/30/realtime-with-signalr-and-azure-mobile-net-backend.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm also looking into node.js with NodeChat, but this SignalR combined with Azure Service Bus seems like it'd be a more "native" solution. I'm open to other options though.